# How to disable closing-bracket comments in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable closing-bracket comments in Visual Studio Code?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywE3m.png)

Comment: This is related to some extension you have installed. It is not a vs code feature. You'd have to find out what extension it is coming from and then find out if that extension has a setting to disable it, or remove or disable the extension itself.

Comment: Try searching for `lens` in your extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Found the extension! It´s name is "Bracket Lens". You can disable it to remove that comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).